# how to make side by side controlgroups

Tags: jquery-mobile, html

these appear one above the other inside the `data-role="page"` div and I would like them horizontal "side by side" (preferably the second `fieldset` on the right, the first `fieldset` to the left with a shrinking gap spacing them) , does anyone know the "right" way to do this? i.e. so that they are not one above the other but side by side and work with resizing?

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
  <button data-inline="true" data-icon="refresh" data-theme="d">save</button>
  <a href="#" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" data-theme="d" data-rel="back" data-role="button">back</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectallbox" id="selectallbox" class="checkable selectall">
  <label for="selectallbox">select all</label>
</fieldset
```

Comment: use grids http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CjtGs/

Comment: thanks Omar you're a star

Comment: Yes Omar is a star. Jquery mobile guru. Olease omar let us know how did u reach such level of perfection on jqm. What did u study